# Flutter path_provider Error - Could not resolve project :path_provider_linux

Tags: android, android-studio, flutter, dart

I have implemented various methods but errors appear every time I run android.
If you delete the path_provier_macos folder, a linux error appears.
You are currently using path_provier: ^1.6.11. Lowering the path_provier version is the same.
Please tell me the solution.

```
Launching lib/main.dart on Android SDK built for x86 in debug mode...
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Could not determine the dependencies of task ':path_provider:compileDebugAidl'.
> Could not resolve all task dependencies for configuration
':path_provider:debugCompileClasspath'.
   > Could not resolve project :path_provider_macos.
     Required by:
         project :path_provider
      > Unable to find a matching configuration of project :path_provider_macos:
          - None of the consumable configurations have attributes.
   > Could not resolve project :path_provider_linux.
     Required by:
         project :path_provider
      > Unable to find a matching configuration of project :path_provider_linux:
          - None of the consumable configurations have attributes.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to     
get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 12s
Finished with error: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
```

Comment: show your pubspec.yaml file

Comment: i follow this question

Comment: Even the current project does not use path_provider.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- Go to your Flutter sdk folder.
- Go to [.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\ or .pub-cache\hosted\pub.flutter-io.cn\ ]
- Remove all path_provider folders.
- Pub get
- Run your app.

I hope this fix your problem!